How to Avoid Showing reCAPTCHA WebView During Authentication in React Native App Using Firebase
I'm developing a React Native app that uses Firebase for phone authentication. During the signup or login process, a reCAPTCHA WebView appears, asking users to verify they are not robots. This happens both in the simulator and on real devices.
Here is a screenshot of the WebView that appears:
For a better user experience, I want to avoid showing this WebView. I've read that it is possible to use an invisible reCAPTCHA verifier, but I'm not sure how to implement this in my React Native app.

Configure invisible reCAPTCHA in your Firebase project settings:

Go to the Firebase Console.
Select your project.
Navigate to Authentication > Sign-in method.
Scroll down to Phone and click on the reCAPTCHA settings.
Enable the invisible reCAPTCHA.

Setup Invisible reCAPTCHA: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/phone-auth#use-invisible-recaptcha
This setup ensures that the reCAPTCHA verifier operates invisibly, improving the user experience by not displaying the WebView during the authentication process.
Related to the library, I am not sure currently what is the last/best one, but there are a couple, for instance:

https://github.com/expo/expo-firebase-recaptcha (this one there used to be a good one, but it looks like deprecated now)
https://github.com/bilaleren/react-native-google-recaptcha
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-recaptcha-that-works

